# AlamofireImage sets startRequestsImmediately to false on initialisation

Tags: alamofire, alamofireimage

I have a custom SessionManager `CustomSessionManager` which I am using to construct the ImageDownloader of Alamofire like this

```
let imageDownloader = ImageDownloader(sessionManager: CustomSessionManager.shared)
```

In the initialiser the ImageDownloader sets the `startRequestImmdediately` to false. Due to this, all the requests using `CustomSessionManager` fail to start.

What is the downside of setting `startRequestImmdediately` to `true`?. Does it have any negative impact?.

Answer (score 0):

As one might see from `AlamofireImage` code inspection, setting `startRequestImmdediately` to `false` is needed for keeping simultaneous downloads count under control (below `maximumActiveDownloads`).

Alamofire request is created but not started until we have free connection slots.